# Golang SSH client handshake failed: ssh: host key mismatch

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to establish SSH Connection to remote server using public Key certificate. I am using golang `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` pkg. I am validating host authenticity with `knownhosts.New` and  my config looks like this.

```
hostkeyCallback, err = knownhosts.New("/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts")

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            user,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.PublicKeys(certSigner),
    },
    HostKeyAlgorithms: []string{
        ssh.KeyAlgoED25519,
    },
    Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
    HostKeyCallback: hostkeyCallback,
}

// Establish connection 
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", ip+":22", config)
```

This gives me `ssh: handshake failed: ssh: host key mismatch`.
I checked the `.ssh/known_hosts` file and it's looking good. I don't see any duplicate entry or so.

Also, the output format of `hostkeyCallback` is JSON and which is not supported. surprisingly This is what I get in Info logs of `hostkeyCallback`.

```
"HostcallBack","Value: Error":"json: unsupported type: ssh.HostKeyCallback"
```

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Run `ssh` (I assume that works) with the verbose flag and check the output. It may give you a better idea of what's supposed to happen.

Comment: For `ssh: host key mismatch` may cause by invalid `certSigner`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt manually executing `sudo -u  user ssh -F /home/user/.ssh/config1 HostName/IP` allows me to access system without any issue

Comment: What's the `sudo -u user` doing there?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt its because we want to perform ssh as sudo user

Comment: That and possibly file permissions is something that can go wrong. Can you determine whether that has any relevance?